# How to output array of doubles to hard drive?

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to output an array of doubles to the hard drive.

edit:

for further clarification. I would like to output it to a file on the hard drive (I/O functions). Preferably in a file format that can be quickly translated back into an array of doubles in another program. It would also be nice if it was stored in a standard 4 byte configuration so that i can look at it through a hex viewer and see the actual values.

Comment: Do you mean, to output to a file?

Comment: To the hard drive? Be specific. To a text file? In what format? 1 per line?...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hey... so you want to do it in a single write/read, well its not too hard, the following code should work fine, maybe need some extra error checking but the trial case was successful:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

bool saveArray( const double* pdata, size_t length, const std::string& file_path )
{
    std::ofstream os(file_path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    if ( !os.is_open() )
        return false;
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pdata), std::streamsize(length*sizeof(double)));
    os.close();
    return true;
}

bool loadArray( double* pdata, size_t length, const std::string& file_path)
{
    std::ifstream is(file_path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    if ( !is.is_open() )
        return false;
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pdata), std::streamsize(length*sizeof(double)));
    is.close();
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    double* pDbl = new double[1000];
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++)
        pDbl[i] = double(rand());

    saveArray(pDbl,1000,"test.txt");

    double* pDblFromFile = new double[1000];
    loadArray(pDblFromFile, 1000, "test.txt");

    for (i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++)
    {
        if ( pDbl[i] != pDblFromFile[i] )
        {
            std::cout << "error, loaded data not the same!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( i==1000 )
        std::cout << "success!\n";

    delete [] pDbl;
    delete [] pDblFromFile;

    return 0;
}
```

Just make sure you allocate appropriate buffers! But thats a whole nother topic.

Comment: Strange why this one didn't get voted more, it is actually much better in terms of portability.

Thanks a bunch, it worked great and I learned a few things!

Comment: Not sure why you'd rate this one better for portability. It uses the same binary read/write as my answer and all the portability problems still exist. This one *is* a more complete answer, being a whole program and not just a code snip.

Answer (score 4):

You can use iostream .read() and .write().

It works (very roughly!) like this:

```
double d[2048];
fill(d, d+2048, 0);
ofstream outfile ("save.bin", ios::binary);
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d), sizeof(d));

ifstream infile ("save.bin", ios::binary);
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d), sizeof(d));
```

Note that this is **not portable** between CPU architectures. Some may have **different sizes** of double. Some may store the bytes in a **different order**. It shouldn't be used for data files that move between machines or data that is sent over the network.

Comment: I would bold the whole first sentence of your disclaimer.

Comment: I know this is being picky, but file should be *.txt if you are saving as binary.

Comment: meant to say _shouldn't_ be *.txt

Comment: I implemented this and I ended up getting strange errors all over the place, actually random strange errors that sometimes happen, and sometimes don't...even between two separate, yet identical runs of the program.

Comment: You have to set the array to something before you use it. The code sample is not something you can use as-is, it is just an example.

Comment: No I realize that, and I did exactly that except it kept giving me access violations randomly...to be honest, I wouldn't even know where to begin explaining my problem other than every few runs or so, i would run into an access violation. Something which I know my code did not produce...i spent 3 hours looking at thousands of variables and finding nothing wrong...except that one error i made, which even after corrected, the program would still give me access violations until i removed the writing bit of code and replaced it with the code in the picked answer.

Comment: It could be the sizeof(d) thing. That only works if the array is in scope. If used on a pointer it returns the size of the pointer. 4 bytes usually. In that case you need length*sizeof(double) instead of sizeof(d)

Answer (score 4):

Use std::copy() with the stream iterators. This way if you change 'data' into another type the alterations to code would be trivial.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    double         data[1000] = {/*Init Array */};

    {
        // Write data too a file.
        std::ofstream   outfile("data");
        std::copy(data,
                  data+1000,
                  std::ostream_iterator<double>(outfile," ")
                 );
    }

    {
        // Read data from a file
        std::ifstream    infile("data");
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(infile),
                  std::istream_iterator<double>(),
                  data // Assuming data is large enough.
                 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this style but its even better if you use a vector<double> instead of an array and back_inserter(data) instead of data in the copy from ifstream.

Comment: Or a list or a set or just about anything else. They all work with only minor change.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream.h>

void saveArray(double* array, int length);

int main()
{
    double array[] = { 15.25, 15.2516, 84.168, 84356};
    saveArray(array, 4);

    return 0;
}

void saveArray(double* array, int length)
{
    ofstream output("output.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        output<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

here is a way to output an array of doubles to text file one per line. hope this helps

**EDIT**
Change top one line to this two, and it will compile in VS. You can use multithreading to not blocking system wile saving data

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your response. It doesn't seem to compile on my VC++ for some reason. Even though it doesn't compile, there still is the problem of using the loop to output everything. In my experience its much slower than using .write() . Since I'm outputting millions of doubles, it would be very very slow, i need something that is fast and efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel old. I asked this question a long time ago (except about ints).
[comp.lang.c++ link](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/308432a56e44ff85/b047504449b23baf?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=tmoore++dodge+c%2B%2B&pli=1)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  double [] theArray=...;
  int arrayLength=...;
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
    myfile << theArray[i]<<"\n";
  }
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

adapted from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Just set theArray and arrayLength to whatever your code requires.

Comment: Do you mean myfile << theArray[i] << "\n"; ? Otherwise you'll just repeatedly be printing the literal "theArray[i]".

Comment: Is there any other method other than outputting each element individually? It's much too slow for my application. Is there some way to say to the computer: "hey! Take the stuff the double array is stored on in RAM and just dump it into a file and slap a .txt on the end of it" ?

Comment: If writing each element is too slow, why not just construct a string of all the entries and write that one string to disk?

Comment: Disk caching makes writing every one individually just as fast as writing it all at once.