# Optimisation: Shrinking file size in C or C++

Tags: c++, optimization, fstream, filesize

When performing computer simulations of systems with `n` (e.g. 10000) particles, the usual workflow involves saving the state of the system frequently at given intervals. This would entail writing down in a file the position coordinates of all the particles (so 3 floats/doubles per line, each line for a particle), with some header information. The floating precision is set to a fixed value.

The way I usually save/write down my configuration files is as follows (part of a function that creates the file whenever called):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

ofstream outfile(filelabel, ios::out);
outfile.precision(10);

outfile << "#Number of particles " << npart << endl;

for (int i=0; i<npart; i++){
outfile << particle[i].pos[0] << " " << particle[i].pos[1] << " " << particle[i].pos[2] << endl;
}

outfile.close();
```

Typically, each such file for a large enough system will have a size of 0.5-4 MB, so when saving them frequently they do add up to a large size at end. So I'm trying to learn how I could optimize the size of my configuration files to bare minimum, e.g. by (2 thoughts that come to mind):

- Using a different method of writing, and not necessarily writing '.txt' files.
- Possibly compressing (e.g. zipping) the data before writing to file.

Any suggestions and recommendations for how I could shrink the size of the configuration files within C/C++ possibilities would be highly appreciated.

---

**Small addendum**

As per the suggestions so far, the binary format for saving seems to be a very good alternative approach, however, as a follow-up question, would one be able to read the so binary saved data in Python for example?

This is relevant as given the saved config files, I tend to use Python for my post-analysis purposes.

Comment: Can you just enable compression on your filesystem?

Comment: Do you need the files to be portable? If not, then save the raw binary data by writing the `pos` array directly to a file opened in binary mode.

Comment: Unless you need human readable files I'd store the information in binary form.  That costs you 24 bytes per particle instead of `width characters * 3 + 2`

Comment: For future questions, please don't add unrelated language tags, like the C tag for a C++ question.

Comment: Storing the values in raw binary instead of textual also means you don't have to worry about reproducibility (when loaded again on the same machine/program).

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude using [std::to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) also allows roundtripping.

Comment: @NathanOliver How can I do that? and later for post-analysis can I convert it to a readable format? It'd be really could if you could show an example.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well sometimes I do resume the work on my laptop, so portability in that sense would be helpful. Does this mean I cannot save as binary? (first time I hear this in context of formats of file saving)

Comment: @user929304 See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090428/how-to-output-array-of-doubles-to-hard-drive) for how to write an array in binary format.  If you ever need to see the data then you can write another program that reads in the binary file and outputs it back out like how you are doing currently.

Comment: Now that really depends on the systems you want to run on. If you use a "standard" x86-based (32 or 64 bit) PC-type computer for both systems, then the file should be portable even between operating systems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wow brilliant! And could one read/load it in another language such as Python? (as that's what I use for post-analysis tasks).

Comment: I don't think its possible to read the data from Python directly, but I think there are ways to "translate" the data from the raw binary form to Python numbers.

Comment: You could use something like EBML (Extensible Binary Meta Language) for portability.

Comment: @IanAbbott how would EMBL be space efficient? Any markup language is verbose by its nature.

Comment: @daShier It's not a text mark-up language, it's an extensible binary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four suggestions:

1. Saving vector information (direction and offset) should take less space than saving X-Y-Z coordinates. But that means keeping a reference to the initial state file - which is more computationally intensive.
2. Assuming the above method is not practical, then I would still consider using vectors if storage space is more critical than computational time. A 3D vector encodes the location in 2 values instead of three, so even if you reference all locations from the origin instead of the particle's previous location, the files should be nearly 30% smaller (assuming a requirement for greater precision in storing the vectors).
3. How "random" are the location coordinates? If there's some correlation, then I would keep the data in text and use a lossless file compression method (such as the suggestion to save the files on a disk that supports filesystem compression - which means *no* work for you!) Any repeating strings of characters will get compressed and could be more efficient than a binary file - if the data has repeating strings. If the coordinates appear pseudo-random, then compression (like ZIP format) won't buy you anything and you should use the binary value method.
4. If storing in binary (perhaps even in text) consider converting the floating point values into integers that fit your volume/precision before writing them to the file. This will take far less space than storing floating point (or worse double) values. That of course assumes that the precision you need can be represented within the precision of an `int` (or a `long`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh the positions are quite random! Regarding point 4., could you kindly please expand upon possibly a dummy example? Indeed the target precision is known (10 decimal places), and if I do proceed with the binary format, would I be able to load/read it in Python for example?

Comment: @user929304 What I mean about converting to `int` is that you define your space using a minimum distance, so for example if the coordinates are in meters, but the total volume is smaller than 10m^3 and you have 10 decimal places, then you are at 10^12 as your largest coordinate value. Unfortunately, that's too big for an `int`, but it will easily fit in a `long`. Sadly, a `long` is the same size as a `double`. On the other hand, if you have 10 decimal places, but your largest value is < 0.01, then you really have less than an `int` of precision. Regardless, I would use the vector method.

Comment: @user929304 forgot to mention: Since you say the positions are random, then I would probably forgo the idea of using text compression. It works by finding repeating patterns and encoding them as a smaller code. If the text is random, the compressed file will actually be slightly _larger_ than the original. I truly think that storing vector data is the way to go here.

Comment: I think the compressed file will be smaller than the original .txt file but larger than a binary file. Although this is easy to check. I mean just compress the text file with a good compression method like xz

Comment: @daShier Thanks for getting back to me! I am currently unable to get a first version running, basically what I have tried is: `ofstream outfile("test.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);` then looping over each particle to write to file: `for (int i=0; i<npart; i++){ outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(particle[i].pos),streamsize(3*sizeof(double))); }` and closing `outfile.close().` But I get segmentation faults, additionally I don't know how to set up the precision, my guess is I am doing something very wrong in the `outfile.write(...)` argument.

Comment: @user929304 Your error appears to be in the casting, but this is a subject for another question instead of continuing the thread here.

Comment: @daShier Posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397530/issues-saving-double-as-binary-in-c), may have managed to solve it on my own (see my addendum in that post). ;)