# Issues saving double as binary in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles

In my simulation code for a particle system, I have a class defined for particles, and each particle has a property of `pos` containing its position, which is a `double pos[3];` as there are 3 coordinate components per particle. So with particle object defined by `particles = new Particle[npart];` (as we have `npart` many particles), then e.g. the y-component of the 2nd particle would be accessed with `double dummycomp = particles[1].pos[1];`

To save the particles to file before using binary I would use (saved as txt, with float precision of `10` and one particle per line):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

ofstream outfile("testConfig.txt", ios::out);
outfile.precision(10);

  for (int i=0; i<npart; i++){
    outfile << particle[i].pos[0] << " " << particle[i].pos[1]  << " " << particle[i].pos[2] << endl;
}
outfile.close();
```

But now, to save space, I am trying to save the configuration as a binary file, and my attempt, inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090428/how-to-output-array-of-doubles-to-hard-drive), has been as follows:

```
ofstream outfile("test.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

for (int i=0; i<npart; i++){ 
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(particle[i].pos),streamsize(3*sizeof(double))); 
}
outfile.close();
```

but I am facing a segmentation fault when trying to run it. My questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong with `reinterpret_cast` or rather in the argument of `streamsize()`?
- Ideally, it would be great if the saved binary format could also be read within Python, is my approach (once fixed) allowing for that?

---

**working example for the old saving approach (non-binary):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
class Particle {

 public:

  double pos[3];

};


int main() {

  int npart = 2;
  Particle particles[npart];
  //initilizing the positions:
  particles[0].pos[0] = -74.04119568;
  particles[0].pos[1] = -44.33692582;
  particles[0].pos[2] = 17.36278231;

  particles[1].pos[0] = 48.16310086;
  particles[1].pos[1] = -65.02325252;
  particles[1].pos[2] = -37.2053818;

  ofstream outfile("testConfig.txt", ios::out);
  outfile.precision(10);

    for (int i=0; i<npart; i++){
      outfile << particles[i].pos[0] << " " << particles[i].pos[1]  << " " << particles[i].pos[2] << endl;
  }
  outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And in order to save the particle positions as binary, substitute the saving portion of the above sample with

```
  ofstream outfile("test.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

  for (int i=0; i<npart; i++){
  outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(particles[i].pos),streamsize(3*sizeof(double))); 
  }
  outfile.close();
```

---

**2nd addendum: reading the binary in Python**

I managed to read the saved binary in python as follows using numpy:

```
data = np.fromfile('test.bin', dtype=np.float64)
data
array([-74.04119568, -44.33692582,  17.36278231,  48.16310086,
       -65.02325252, -37.2053818 ])
```

But given the doubts cast in the comments regarding non-portability of binary format, I am not confident this type of reading in Python will always work! It would be really neat if someone could elucidate on the reliability of such approach.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to specify the direction when using `ifstream` and `ofstream`; the "i" means "in", and the "o" means "out", and you only rarely need to explicitly close any of them - the destructor takes care of that.

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel. Use a sane library for serialization like [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) or [Boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: What is the definition of `pos`?  Is it `[3]`?

Comment: *So with particle object defined by particles = new Particle[npart];* -- Where?  Comments and descriptions are not the truth, only the code is the truth.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @wallyk yes indeed as written at the top of the question: `double pos[3];`

Comment: Whenever you need to reach for `reinterpret_cast`, you need to stop and think "am I writing a bug here" and the answer is *usually* "yes".

Comment: Oh, it don't see it in code.  Just a description which, as a long time SO member, often doesn't match reality unfortunately.

Comment: @nada means you are using serialization to reduce the size of your data, whether you realize it or not. This can be tricky, so using one of the libraries he linked to do it for you may be advantageous.

Comment: See also [std::to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) and [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).

Comment: @user929304 http://cpp.sh/5nf2s your code seems to work fine (even though I agree you should not reinvent the wheel). Are you sure that your program segfaults exactly there? If so, there must be a different reason for that.

Comment: `Particle particles[npart];` -- This is not standard C++.  Just put a `2` in there instead of a variable or make `npart` a `const int`.

Comment: @freakish that's true! thanks for also checking! I have now provided a working example in the post. But for saving as binary, I don't know 2 things: i) how to set the precision of the double for saving and ii) once saved, can we read the binary file within Python? Any hints would be really helpful.

Comment: @user929304 I can answer your precision question straight ahead: there is no such thing. Precision only matters when you transform from floating point format to human format (or vice versa). In binary format double is double, exactly 64 bits.

Comment: @user929304 *once saved, can we read the binary file within Python?* -- You would be lucky if you could read it using another brand or version of a C++ compiler, let alone Python.  Unless you have a description of the file, there is no guarantee any other language will be able to "read it" just like that.  That's why other binary file formats have a document describing the layout of the file, so that language X can tailor their input routines in accordance with the layout description.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie managed to find a way to read in python, see my new edit! One question if I may: when I give the following argument (when saving as binary in my code above) `streamsize(3*sizeof(double))`, I don't know what it means! I just know I should use `3` because I have 3 components per particle, does `sizeof(double)` mean 64 bits or 32 bits given my os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that base 10 representation of double in ascii is flawed and not guaranteed to give you the correct result (especially if you only use 10 digits). There is a potential for a loss of information even if you use all `std::numeric_limits<max_digits10>` digits as the number may not be representable in base 10 exactly.

The other issue you have is that the binary representation of a double is not standardized so using it is very fragile and can lead to code breaking very easily. Simply changing the compiler or compiler sittings can result in a different double format and changing architectures you have absolutely no guarantees.

You can serialize it to text in a non lossy representation by using the hex format for doubles.

```
 stream << std::fixed << std::scientific << particles[i].pos[0];

 // If you are using C++11 this was simplified to

 stream << std::hexfloat << particles[i].pos[0];
```

This has the affect of printing the value with the same as "%a" in `printf()` in C, that prints the string as "Hexadecimal floating point, lowercase". Here both the `radix` and `mantissa` are converted into hex values before being printed in a very specific format. Since the underlying representation is binary these values can be represented exactly in hex and provide a non lossy way of transferring data between systems. IT also truncates proceeding and succeeding zeros so for a lot of numbers is relatively compact.

On the python side. This format is also supported. You should be able to read the value as a string then convert it to a float using `float.fromhex()`

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex

But your goal is to save space:

> But now, to save space, I am trying to save the configuration as a binary file.

I would ask the question do you really need to save space? Are you running on a low powered low resource environment? Sure then space saving can definitely be a thing (but that is rare nowadays (but these environments do exist)).

But it seems like you are running some form of particle simulation. This does not scream low resource use case. Even if you have tera bytes of data I would still go with a portable easy to read format over binary. Preferably one that is not lossy. Storage space is cheap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the explanations, this has been really helpful! Really interesting idea to use hexfloat! I am going to give it a go now!

Comment: Hi Martin, I don't manage to write to file using hexfloat, is there a trick to this? (that is within `outfile.write(...)` in the above code snippet. Thanks for any hints on this.

Comment: @user929304 `outfile << std::hexfloat << particles[i].pos[0] < " ";`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a *library* instead of writing a serialization/deserialization routine from scratch. I find [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) really easy to use, maybe even easier than [boost::serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). It reduces the opportunity for bugs in your own code.

In your case I'd go about serializing `double`s like this using cereal:

```cpp
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream outfile("test.bin", ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive out(outfile);
    double x, y, z;
    x = y = z = 42.0;
    out(x, y, z);
}
```

To deserialize them you'd use:

```cpp
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("test.bin", ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive in(infile);
    double x,y,z;
    in(x, y, z);
}
```

You can also serialize/deserialize whole `std::vector<double>`s in the same fashion. Just add `#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>` and use `in` / `out` like in the given example on a single `std::vector<double>` instead of multiple `double`s.

Ain't that swell.

---

**Edit**

In a comment you asked, *whether it'd be possible to read a created binary file like that with Python.*

*Answer:*

Serialized binary files aren't really meant to be very portable (things like endianness *could* play a role here). You could easily adapt the example code I gave you to write a [JSON](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html#json) file (another advantage of using a library) and [read that format in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html).

Oh and `cereal::JSONOutputArchive` has an [option for setting precision](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/assets/doxygen/classcereal_1_1JSONOutputArchive_1_1Options.html).

Comment: You probably need `trunc` and `out` flags for `outfile` and `in` for `infile`.

Comment: Remember: [std::to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) / [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars). No extra libraries (beyond the C++ standard library) required.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `ifstream` is `in` by default as is `out` for `ofstream`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl From [OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395488/optimisation-shrinking-file-size-in-c-or-c) I deduced it'd best to recommend a "complete" solution to the problem. Oh and cereal is header only so minimal effort there (to include).

Comment: Follow-up questions: i) How do you set the decimal places before saving as binary? (in the old approach, I used `outfile.precision(10);` ii) Could we also read the resulting binary in Python?

Comment: @user929304 You asked about binary file format, which is non-portable in general. Cereal supports [JSON](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html#json) (or XML), which both would also be supported by Python.

Comment: @nada thanks again for the prompt follow-up! I also added another addendum showing how I managed to read my example binary file in python! Seems to work properly!

Comment: The whole purpose of this in the other question was the OP wanted a smaller file than text file containing the 3 floating point numbers separated by a space. XML or JSON would be generating a larger file than the original. Or am I wrong??

Comment: @drescherjm You are not wrong, you are correct. XML or JSON would be larger but portable. Binary would be smaller, but non-portable. A compromise would be a [portable binary](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html) or a compressed XML/JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious if you ever investigated the idea of converting your data to vectored coordinates instead of Cartesian X,Y,Z? It would seem that this would potentially reduce the size of your data by about 30%: Two coordinates instead of three, but perhaps needing slightly higher precision in order to convert back to your X,Y,Z.

The vectored coordinates could still be further optimized by using the various compression techniques above (text compression or binary conversion).